# Wrong characters in Java XML?

Tags: java, xml, encoding, jaxb

I have the following problem:
For a project I created my own logger, which produces an xml file with custom tags.
The problem is that both using DOM and JAXB to create the XML probably have problems in encoding. Since the "content" field always produces incorrect characters.
I have already tried to change the encoding with UTF-8 / windows-1252.
I found that in reality the project that I then run the logger on uses ISO-8859-1 I tried to replace that too, but nothing. As output of the content field I always get these incomprehensible characters.
Can anyone help me?

My Code:

```
        if (OS.contains("Window")) {

            try {

                fh = new FileHandler(userDir+s+logF+s+jade+s+nameAgent+"-receive(Logger Java).xml" );
                logger.addHandler(fh);
                XMLFormatter formatter = new XMLFormatter();  
                fh.setFormatter(formatter);  
                logger.info(" ");

            }

            catch (SecurityException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
        }


        XmlCreator xmlcreator = new XmlCreator();
        xmlcreator.setOntology(onto);
        xmlcreator.setPerformative(perf);
        xmlcreator.settimeStamp(ts);
        xmlcreator.setProtocol(pro);
        xmlcreator.setReceiver(rec);
        xmlcreator.setContent(con);

        try {

            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Francesco\\Desktop\\writereceiver.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlCreator.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(xmlcreator, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(xmlcreator, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output XML (problem in content tag) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xmlCreator>
    <content>Â¬Ã­ sr pojo.SongRequestInfoÃƒÃcÃ€WCÃ«</content>
    <performative>ACCEPT-PROPOSAL</performative>
    <receiver>jade.util.leap.ArrayList$1@445c4a59</receiver>
    <timeStamp>1583849551513</timeStamp>
</xmlCreator>
```

Comment: What's in `con`? What type is it? How is it defined? Who fills it? Show the relevant code, pleass.

Comment: It looks like the XML file is correct, and it’s your method of viewing the output that isn’t recognizing that the output is UTF-8.

Comment: con and all other are string

Comment: I use atom what i have to do, to see it correct? I've alredy tried chang encoding with UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @VCR. In all likelihood the output XML is a correctly encoded UTF-8 XML document, and it only looks odd because you are looking at it using some piece of software that doesn't know how to display UTF-8.

The prevalence of character pairs starting `Â` is symptomatic of what happens when you display UTF-8 data using software that thinks it is displaying iso-8859-1.